# JavaScript - Showing old radio button selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm building a simple quiz app in JavaScript, where users can select answers via radio buttons. When each question is answered, I push their answers to an array. (Week 6 Assignment of http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/

I'm trying to build a "back" button where users can click back to previously answered questions. How can I have these radio buttons display their previously selected answer, so they don't have to re-answer the questions?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can get the question number and get the answer in the array according to the question number that was selected.

Comment: I understand that, I just want the page to display that radio button pre-selected. how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving some value when the radio button is checked and when the back button is clicked,check for that value and if it satisfies the condition use this `$('input[name="correctAnswer"]').attr('checked', true);`

Answer (score 0):

i think you can push question and answer to array:
exam:

```
var list = [
{question: 'foo',answerList:[{name: 'number 1'},{name: 'number 2'}], answer: 1},
//..........
];
```

then check question number -> get data in variable "list" -> render html